# Can't connect to mysql without port number using PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo, localhost

I am unable to install Impresspages and others scripts on `localhost` with PDO,  because port number is required. How can I disable using port number on PDO?

Comment: default mysql port number is 3306 (you can't disable using port- it just doesn't make any sense)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking but if you are looking for default mysql port number then it is **3306**

Comment: I can't connect to mysql without using port number but the script hasn't that option.

Comment: can you post  the connection method for the script ?

Comment: try `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname; port=1234; dbname=dbnameHere; charset=utf8', 'dbuser', 'password');` after tweaking all that is necessary

Answer (score 0):

The database server PDO is connecting to is available on a particular port. By default that port is `3306`, but a port is required so that the database knows where to listen and what to respond on. The port it is doing this on is explicitly defined in the database you're using, though, as stated, the default is `3306` and is unlikely to have been changed.